# Swift: How to put a MapView in UIView (?)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiview

I'm pretty new in programming so I need a little bit of help. I write in Swift without using the Storyboard. I want to add a MKMapView(?) if you can say so? On a UIView. The problem is that I can't do that because it cannot convert the value/type to UIView. I have to write it in a UIViewController class. How I'm going to solve this? I don't know which codes I have to show you...

But my app look like pretty much the same as the app in the video in the link. [look att 5:08](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77nQN0JzBH4)

I want to have a Map inside of one of these cells.

Hope someone can help me!:)

Edit: I add the codes

Here is the "Map" codes that I'm uing:

```
    import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var window: UIWindow?
var mapView: MKMapView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, (self.window?.frame.width)!, 300))
    self.view.addSubview(self.mapView!)


}

}
```

In this block (if you can say so?) can I change the cell that I want. You can se that I've changed the color to red. I think it there I have to implement the Map but I can't.

```
import UIKit

import MapKit


class MapCell1: MapCell, MKMapViewDelegate {



override func setupViews() {


        backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


}


}
```

And MapCell1 is a subclass of MapCell, and the Mapcell looks like this:

```
import UIKit
class MapCell: BaseCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor() //Here can I change the color in the whole UIcollectionView. So every three cells are gray right now.
    return cv
}()



let cellId = "cellId"

override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()


    addSubview(collectionView)
    addconstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
    addconstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)


}

}
```

And I don't know if these codes will help but I add them too.

```
 import UIKit

class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

func setupViews() {

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

}

class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    func setupViews() {

    }


}
}
```

And

```
    import UIKit

class MenuBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(61, green: 91, blue: 151)
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    return cv
}()

let cellId = "cellId"
let imageNames = ["LocationMarker", "MapFeed", "ProfilePicture" ]

var viewController: ViewController?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    collectionView.registerClass(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    addSubview(collectionView)
    addconstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
    addconstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)

    let selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
    collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)

    setupHorizontalBar()
}

var horizontalBarLefAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

func setupHorizontalBar() {
    let horizontalBarView = UIView()
    horizontalBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    horizontalBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(horizontalBarView)

    horizontalBarLefAnchorConstraint = horizontalBarView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.leftAnchor)
    horizontalBarLefAnchorConstraint?.active = true
    horizontalBarView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomAnchor).active = true
    horizontalBarView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/4).active = true
    horizontalBarView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(4).active = true
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

//        print(indexPath.item)
//        let x = CGFloat(indexPath.item) * frame.width / 2.65
//        horizontalBarLefAnchorConstraint?.constant = x
//        
//        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
//            self.layoutIfNeeded()
// 

       }, completion: nil)

    viewController?.scrollToMenuIndex(indexPath.item)


}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuCell

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[indexPath.item])?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(39, green: 58, blue: 97)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(frame.width / 3, frame.height)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}


class MenuCell: BaseCell {

let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "LocationMarker")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    iv.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(39, green: 58, blue: 97)
    return iv
}()

override var highlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        imageView.tintColor = highlighted ? UIColor.whiteColor() : UIColor.rgb(39, green: 58, blue: 97)
    }
}

override var selected: Bool {
    didSet {
        imageView.tintColor = selected ? UIColor.whiteColor() : UIColor.rgb(39, green: 58, blue: 97)
    }
}
override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    addSubview(imageView)
    addconstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(28)]", views: imageView)
    addconstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(28)]", views: imageView)

    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

}

}
```

Comment: Please add the code here in the question.  Videos can disappear over time and watching a video is a high barrier to entry for people to answer your question.

Welcome to the site.  Please format your questions with as much detail as possible so that answers can help others as well as yourself.

Comment: As @BlueJ774 says this is important to clearly explain your issue. Also try to explain your attempts to solve that issue. That way others will see that you are not just waiting for the answer, and they won't have to guess what you have already try or not (you won't have answers you have already try ;) ). A good example of this would be to add links of relative questions, or links to a tutorial you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the tips, I've added som codes now and I hope it will helps:)

Answer (score 1):

set the custom class to your view with MKMapView.
[image: see below screenshot]

Comment: add MKMapView for your view

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I just could not find.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I think this is what you want

```
import MapKit

func initMapView() {
    let mapView = MKMapView()
    mapView.delegate = self
    ...
    self.view.addSubView(mapView)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! How do you mean more exactly? I now have added some codes in the question if it helps you to give an answer.